# What is the correct phrase? Should it be "I couldn't help to think that" or " I can't help to think"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

I had a sentence that goes like this "I ----- help to think that you said I should give you the goods for free" do the omitted word sound like "couldn't" or "can't" so what's the correct word and the meaning of the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual expression is *I can't help thinking that...*, meaning *it seems to me - I cannot avoid having the opinion that...* Whether you use *can't* or *couldn't* depends on whether you are referring to the present or the past.

It seems odd, though, to use the expression with *you said.* Surely the speaker knows whether or not the other person said something? A more likely version would be:

> I can't help thinking that you wanted me to give you the goods for free.